# Display all POST value for ASIHTTPRequest client

Tags: ios, iphone, asihttprequest

Is there a way to display all post value for ASIHTTPRequest

I hope to analyze the other wrote ASIHTTPRequestcode.

Comment: Only at the server or by rigging-up some sort of proxy that can intercept the traffic.  It's a lot of hassle, however.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to post something, please use ASIFormDataRequest. it's perfect for POST request.
2. you can still get text by this way:

in ASIHTTPRequest.m, line 954, add

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.postBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

and you will get the post body